# Adding /GENPROFILE to Sharpmake for PGO instrumentation

Tags: c#, c++, build, visual-studio-2019

How to add /GENPROFILE and /USEPROFILE tags to sharpmake?

I'm trying to enable the PGO flags for my project using sharpmake. I'm trying to add /GL, /LTCG and /GENPROFILE to instrument. But there are no equivalent flags for /GENPROFILE. I tried creating a new variable GenProfile in the LinkTimeCodeGenertion enum :

```
public enum LinkTimeCodeGeneration
                {
                    [Default]
                    Default,
                    UseLinkTimeCodeGeneration,
                    GenProfile,
                    ProfileGuidedOptimizationInstrument,
                    ProfileGuidedOptimizationOptimize,
                    ProfileGuidedOptimizationUpdate
                }
```

and mapped it to /GENPROFILE :

```
if (context.Configuration.Output == Project.Configuration.OutputType.Lib)
            {
                context.SelectOption
                (
                Options.Option(Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration.Default, () => { context.Options["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "false"; context.CommandLineOptions["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = FileGeneratorUtilities.RemoveLineTag; }),
                Options.Option(Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration.UseLinkTimeCodeGeneration, () => { context.Options["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "true"; context.CommandLineOptions["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "/LTCG"; }),
                Options.Option(Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration.GenProfile, () => { context.Options["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "true"; context.CommandLineOptions["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "/GENPROFILE"; }),
                Options.Option(Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration.ProfileGuidedOptimizationInstrument, () => { context.Options["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "true"; context.CommandLineOptions["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "/LTCG"; }),
                Options.Option(Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration.ProfileGuidedOptimizationOptimize, () => { context.Options["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "true"; context.CommandLineOptions["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "/LTCG"; }),
                Options.Option(Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration.ProfileGuidedOptimizationUpdate, () => { context.Options["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "true"; context.CommandLineOptions["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "/LTCG"; })
                );
            }
            else
            {
                context.SelectOption
                (
                Options.Option(Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration.Default, () => { context.Options["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "Default"; context.CommandLineOptions["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = FileGeneratorUtilities.RemoveLineTag; }),
                Options.Option(Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration.UseLinkTimeCodeGeneration, () => { context.Options["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "UseLinkTimeCodeGeneration"; context.CommandLineOptions["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "/LTCG"; }),
                Options.Option(Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration.GenProfile, () => { context.Options["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "GenProfile"; context.CommandLineOptions["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "/GENPROFILE"; }),
                Options.Option(Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration.ProfileGuidedOptimizationInstrument, () => { context.Options["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "PGInstrument"; profileGuideOptimization = true; context.CommandLineOptions["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "/LTCG:PGInstrument"; }),
                Options.Option(Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration.ProfileGuidedOptimizationOptimize, () => { context.Options["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "PGOptimization"; profileGuideOptimization = true; context.CommandLineOptions["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "/LTCG:PGOptimize"; }),
                Options.Option(Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration.ProfileGuidedOptimizationUpdate, () => { context.Options["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "PGUpdate"; profileGuideOptimization = true; context.CommandLineOptions["LinkTimeCodeGeneration"] = "/LTCG:PGUpdate"; })
                );
            }
```

However i'm getting, error CS0117: 'Sharpmake.Options.Vc.Linker.LinkTimeCodeGeneration' does not contain a definition for 'GenProfile'