# /USEPROFILE command isn't giving PGO logs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, lto, pgo

Trying to create an optimized executable after creating an instrumented build using /GL,/LTCG and /FASTGENPROFILE and /USEPROFILE

I'm trying to create an optimized executable after creating an instrumented build usinf /GL,/LTCG and /FASTGENPROFILE. I'm able to create the necessary .pgc files with this but on changing /FASTGENPROFILE to /USEPROFILE to actually create the optimized executable, i'm not seeing any PGO related logs in the build output.

[The log is supposed to look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gory3.png)

I don't understand if the executable is already optimized and it just doesn't show in the logs or /USEPROFILE is working at all

Comment: From the  thread :[Adding /GENPROFILE to Sharpmake for PGO instrumentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76337823/adding-genprofile-to-sharpmake-for-pgo-instrumentation), do  you want to add /USEPROFILE for sharpmake?

Comment: yeah but it seems /USEPROFILE isn't merging the .pgc and .pgd file like it should. Also i tried /USEPROFILE[:AGGRESSIVE] as well but it's giving me error:  inconsistent option ':AGGRESSIVE' specified with /USEPROFILE but not with /GENPROFILE